# How to disable default browser message “are you sure you want to leave this page” for a Google Form iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I have an `iframe` hidden via a Bootstrap modal which contains a Google Form URL.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="sugestaoPL" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal Title</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <iframe src="<?php echo ot_get_option('iframe_url'); ?>"></iframe>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Everytime I try to leave or reload a page, the browser advices me that default "Are you sure you want to leave this page, unsaved changes will be lost" message, probably because I'm leaving the page with the Google Form untouched.

Since in most use cases my user won't let the modal visible and therefore will not use the Google Form, I'd like to disable this default message. I know the message is coming from the Google Form because if I remove the modal piece of code, the browser message goes away.

The solutions for removing this default behavior I found were about adding a

`window.onbeforeunload = null`

in my code. Which I did. I tried that inside `$(document).ready(){}`, and outside it, in the head and in the footer right before closing the `</body>` tag, and none of the alternatives prevented this dialogue to appear.

I'm afraid that's because it's inside of an `iframe`.

How do I eliminate this default dialogue?

Comment: there's nothing you can do to remedy this. The iframe is out of your control.

Comment: My suggestion is replace the iframe with an image. when clicked, replace the image with an iframe and focus it. This way the iframe won't actually load unless the user tries to focus it. That or don't build the modal's html until you show the modal.

Comment: I did something a little bit different, but the idea is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I wasn't able to fix the main issue, but I found a workaround. As pointed out [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/IOZbEbkxXrE;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Atroubleshoot), this seems like a Google issue with its forms. However the workaround pointed in the link didn't work for me.

This is the workaround that did work

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    if(jQuery('.modal').is(':visible') === false){
        jQuery( ".modal" ).remove();
    }
});
```

What it does is, if there is no modal open when I'm trying to leave the page, then remove the `.modal` element from the page right before the page is onloaded. This way the `iframe` is removed as well and the "Are you sure to leave this page" is gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
   location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
   window.onunload = null;
  } + ")()";
```

take a look at this thread
[reference](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2083577)

Answer (score 0):

if you set window.onbeforeunload = someFunction; you can nullify it with window.onbeforeunload = null.

However, if you set window.addEventListener('beforeunload',someFunction);, this event listener can't be removed with window.onbeforeunload = null. 
It can be removed only with
removeEventListener('beforeunload',someFunction);

Comment: that isn't possible.. that would need to be ran on the iframe, and you don't have access to the iframe.